# Python script not delivering expected output for Vegetation indices (NDVI, CLgreen) using ArcPy and ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, ndvi, pycharm

I have a script that was written in Python in PyCharm.

The script is something meant to run once then all the indices I list in the python can run from PyCharm rather than opening the ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro software everytime.

When running the script I get the NDVI that is expected, however the CLG index does not provide a reading as expected.

The `Clgreen` using the Arcpy provides an output, while the `Clgreen2` using the ArcGIS fails in giving an output.

```
import arcpy
import arcgis
from datetime import date

output = r'C:\Users\john\Desktop\testing\RedEdge\Exports'
raster = r'C:\Users\john\Desktop\testing\RedEdge\Exports\RedEdge.tif'

today = date.today()
date = today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

#formulas - indices
NDVI = arcpy.ia.NDVI(raster, nir_band_id=5, red_band_id=3)
Clgreen = arcpy.ia.CIg(raster,nir_band_id=5, green_band_id=2)
Clgreen2 = arcgis.raster.cig(raster,band_indexes="5 2", astype=None)

#save
Clgreen.save(output+'\\'+date+'_' +'clgreen.tif')
Clgreen2.save(output+'\\'+date+'_' +'clgreen2.tif')
NDVI.save(output+'\\'+date+'_'+'ndvi2.tif')

print('scripting was successfull ! ')
```

[image: Clg Indices in photoviewer]

[image: When imported into GIS]

Image 1 is `Clgreen` in imageviewer and image 2 is in ArcGIS PRO.

- So the questions I have is why is the output of the `Clgreen` not shown
  in ArcMap or ArcGIS pro, but shows fine in imageviewer
- What would the reason be that the `Clgreen2` is failing?

Comment: Try different stretch settings under symbology in ArcMap/Pro

Comment: Thanks @BERA, I did change the Strech to be from - 1 to 5 ( it was at a maximum of 30000) do you perhaps know how to set the maximum in python so it doesnt have a max of 30000?

Comment: @Kübra thanks, but I dont think its the ( Chlorophyll index - green) , the formula requests the NIR and Green bands to calculate the values. BERA indicated the stretch was wrong, which solved the problem i had with "CLgreen". but i am unsure why the " CLgreen2" didnt work, not giving an output and failing.